# Connected locally (LAN) but not to internet

Tags: windows, internet-connection

I have a wireless i-net connection using WRT54G2 Linksys router.

I have never problems being connected to the local network, however the i-net connection seems to be dropping pretty frequently and I am not sure why. In other words, I am connected locally with no internet access.

There are full days when I am online and I have no problems whatsoever but other days when the i-net connection drops a couple of times a day. As you can imagine, it's very annoying having to unplug the router and the modem to get everything back up and running.

Once the modem and router are restarted, I always get connected to the i-net without problems.

Now, I have been trying to figure out the cause of it unsuccessfully.

I compared the records of ipconfig /all when the i-net connection was down vs when I am connected to the i-net.

The records are identical except the last part...

```
----------------- I-net connection working: 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:246b:1aaa:9c03:a390(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::246b:1aaa:9c03:a390%15(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

----------------- I-net connection NOT working: 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I have no idea what "Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:" does..

Can someone please shed some light on this issue? More specifically, what "Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9" is for and whether it could be the cause of my i-net connection dropping on regular basis?

Thank you in advance!

PS: To save time... here is the rest of my ipconfig /all info

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : v-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : phub.net.cable.rogers.com

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 26-17-FE-AA-CD-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-0A-A9-1C-EF-79
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : phub.net.cable.rogers.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-17-FE-AA-CD-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cfd:a772:9ea4:865f%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 17, 2012 11:21:04 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, November 18, 2012 12:10:19 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 197400574
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-E3-2F-1C-C8-0A-A9-1C-EF-79

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 64.71.255.198
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.phub.net.cable.rogers.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : phub.net.cable.rogers.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:246b:1aaa:9c03:a390(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::246b:1aaa:9c03:a390%15(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: As @techie007 noted it is most likely the WRT54G2, what I've done in the past when this starts happening is to reflash the device. You can try using the stock Linksys firmware for the device or you can flash it with a 3rd party one like [dd-wrt](http://dd-wrt.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I have no idea what "Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:" does..**

It provides [IPV6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) support.

> **whether it could be the cause of my i-net connection dropping on regular basis?**

No, that is a fault in your router or a problem with your modem, ADSL-line or cable-connection or ISP.

Instead of unplugging everything, try connecting to the router's administration web-page. From there you should be able to get it to reconnect or to reboot.

If the problem persists, I'd try calling your ISP support and/or changing the ADSL filter, cables or router.

Comment: Thanks guys for your tips. It seems like it was the router after all.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's your WRT54G2 Linksys.

From my experience they fail a lot (especially as they continue to get older), and they fail just like you're describing.  Try a new router.